# How to resolve error Incompatible ssh server (no acceptable ciphers) in python SFTP/paramiko connexion?

Tags: python, paramiko, pysftp

I'm beginner in python, I am looking to automate a file transfer from my computer (windows 10 21H2) to a Linux server (Rocky Linux 8.6) via the SFTP protocol.
I'm using a key pair with passphrase for authentication.

The connection is not successful.
I tried lots of combinations and went through a lot of questions on stackoverflow, without success...

```
import pysftp

host,port = 'monServeur.domaine.fr',22
username='pmartin'
pkey='C:/Users/pmartin/.ssh/myPrivateKey'
passphrase='mypassphrase'

with pysftp.Connection(host=host, username=username, private_key=pkey, port=22, private_key_pass=passphrase) as sftp:
    with sftp.cwd('/home/pmartin'):
        for entry in sftp.listdir_attr():
            print(entry.filename)
```

Error returned :

```
C:\programmation\python>"C:/Program Files/Python310/python.exe" c:/programmation/python/ftptls.py
Exception (client): Incompatible ssh server (no acceptable ciphers)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\omarie\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2138, in run
    self._handler_table[ptype](self, m)
  File "C:\Users\omarie\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2258, in _negotiate_keys
    self._parse_kex_init(m)
  File "C:\Users\omarie\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2511, in _parse_kex_init
    raise IncompatiblePeer(
paramiko.ssh_exception.IncompatiblePeer: Incompatible ssh server (no acceptable ciphers)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programmation\python\ftptls.py", line 9, in <module>
    with pysftp.Connection(host, username, pkey, None, 22, passphrase, ['aes128-cbc','aes192-cbc','aes256-cbc','aes128-ctr','aes192-ctr','aes256-ctr']) as sftp:
  File "C:\Users\omarie\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 143, in __init__
    self._transport.connect(**self._tconnect)
  File "C:\Users\omarie\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1346, in connect
    self.start_client()
  File "C:\Users\omarie\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 699, in start_client
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\omarie\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2138, in run
    self._handler_table[ptype](self, m)
  File "C:\Users\omarie\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2258, in _negotiate_keys
    self._parse_kex_init(m)
  File "C:\Users\omarie\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2511, in _parse_kex_init
    raise IncompatiblePeer(
paramiko.ssh_exception.IncompatiblePeer: Incompatible ssh server (no acceptable ciphers)
```

Versions :

Python 3.10.4 (tags/v3.10.4:9d38120, Mar 23 2022, 23:13:41) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Modules :

- Name: cryptography  Version: 37.0.2
- Name: paramiko  Version: 2.11.0
- Name: pysftp  Version: 0.2.9

Ciphers on the server :

```
[monServeur ~/.ssh]$ ssh -Q cipher
3des-cbc
aes128-cbc
aes192-cbc
aes256-cbc
rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
aes128-ctr
aes192-ctr
aes256-ctr
aes128-gcm@openssh.com
aes256-gcm@openssh.com
chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
```

I tried to add ciphers in pysftp command like this, without success :

```
with pysftp.Connection(host, username, pkey, None, 22, passphrase, ['aes128-cbc','aes192-cbc','aes256-cbc','aes128-ctr','aes192-ctr','aes256-ctr']) as sftp:
```

I'm able to do my transfers with FileZilla and Cyberduck with the keys pair and passphrase without this "cipher problem".

Could someone give me a clue ?

Added : paramiko log file

```
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0x1bf1a6b0
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_2.11.0
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
INFO:paramiko.transport:Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_8.0)
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:=== Key exchange possibilities ===
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex algos: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server key: rsa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256, ssh-rsa, ssh-ed25519
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client encrypt: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com, aes256-gcm@openssh.com   
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server encrypt: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com, aes256-gcm@openssh.com   
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client mac: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server mac: hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client compress: none, zlib@openssh.com
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server compress: none, zlib@openssh.com
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client lang: <none>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server lang: <none>
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:kex follows: False
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:=== Key exchange agreements ===
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:Kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:HostKey: ssh-ed25519
ERROR:paramiko.transport:Exception (client): Incompatible ssh server (no acceptable ciphers)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your server supports only two proprietary OpenSSH ciphers:

```
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:client encrypt: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com, aes256-gcm@openssh.com   
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:server encrypt: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com, aes256-gcm@openssh.com
```

That's indeed quite limited set.

Paramiko does not support those.

You have to reconfigure the server to support some of the ciphers that Paramiko does.